# Windows API not working in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi, crash

It appears as if `GetClassName` and some other Windows APIs do not work at all in WPF and instead crash the application (no Exception). Reproducing it is extremely simple. Here's full code (paste it in `Window1`'s code-behind after you create a new WPF application):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT p);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
      public int X, Y;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      var Pos = e.GetPosition(this);
      var WindowUnderMouse = WindowFromPoint(new POINT() { X = (int)Pos.X, Y = (int)Pos.Y });
      StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
      GetClassName(WindowUnderMouse, SB, 50);
      MessageBox.Show(SB.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

The application crashes for me on `GetClassName` call. I'm using VS2015 + .NET 4.5.

Or is it something on my part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetClassName` works perfectly well. However, you are calling it incorrectly. When you write:

```
GetClassName(WindowUnderMouse, SB, 50);
```

you are promising to provide a buffer of length 50. You don't do this. Instead of:

```
StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
```

use

```
StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(50);
```

Now, the maximum name for a window class is `256`. So I would write the code like so, including error checking:

```
StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(256);
if (GetClassName(WindowUnderMouse, SB, SB.Capacity) == 0)
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

Comment: I really thought `StringBuilder` can expand itself as needed. Let me try.

Comment: It can expand itself as needed, but only when you call its methods. When you call a p/invoke method you are passing the address of the internal buffer to unmanaged Win32 code. That Win32 code does not see the .net object.